# Usage of List instead of ToMany in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

I've read in official documentation of OB that I can use List instead of ToMany class. https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#to-many-relations. But I didn't get it. What exactly is different for me in using of list instead of ToMany? Can I call some new useful functions or it is only internal advantage to use ToMany(faster obtaining of data or smth like that).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the docs that you linked:

```
@Backlink(to = "customer")
public ToMany<Order> orders;
```

Instead you could also use `List`:

```
@Backlink(to = "customer")
public List<Order> orders;
```

As you probably know, List is a standard Java interface and ToMany a concrete class implemented in the ObjectBox API. So by using List, your code is less dependent on ObjectBox. The downside is that you don't have [special methods offered by ToMany](https://objectbox.io/docfiles/java/current/io/objectbox/relation/ToMany.html).